# How to store attributes from a node in a binary tree by doing in-order traversal

Tags: java, tree, binary

```
private void searchAndStore(Node node, String s) {
        if (node == null) {
            return "";
        }

        searchAndStore(node.getR(), s);
        System.out.println(node.getElement());
        searchAndStore(node.getL(), s);
    }
```

I am trying to do a binary search and store the elements in each node in an array in the order of in order traversal.

It's simple enough if I am just printing the result as I've done above, but I am trying to return a String with the same results.

Any insight would be appreciated.

```
private String searchAndStore(Node node, String s) {
        if (node == null) {
            return "";
        }

        s += searchAndStore(node.getR(), s);
        s += node.getElement());
        s += searchAndStore(node.getL(), s);
        return s
    }
```

This doesn't work as nodes are visited multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe adding to the string when you are at the node only will fix this problem.
so:

```
private String searchAndStore(Node node, String s) {
        if (node == null) {
            return "";
        }

        searchAndStore(node.getR(), s);
        s += node.getElement());
        searchAndStore(node.getL(), s);
        return s
    }
```